# Replace all UUID strings with new UUID strings

Tags: linux, bash, uuid

I have a text file contains some different UUID strings in it, I want to replace all the UUID strings by new different UUID strings, how can I do that easily in Bash?

Comment: Maybe useful: http://serverfault.com/questions/103359/how-to-create-a-uuid-in-bash

Comment: I knew how to create UUID hash...

Comment: you need to provide some more information, what does the text file looks like and how is the "new" uuid stored. Need to replace all or just some strings in the text-file?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the uuid format contains only hexadecimals with hyphens between them and these number of chars between each hypen: 8, 4, 4, 4, 12.
I'm also assuming they are on their own line.

```
awk '
{
    if ($0 ~ /^[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}-[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}-[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}-[A-Fa-f0-9]{12}$/)
    {
        system("uuidgen")
    }
    else
    {
        print $0
    }
}' file-with-uuids > new-file-with-uuids

# To override the old file with the new:
mv -f new-file-with-uuids file-with-uuids
```

Comment: getting rid of the assumptions about being on one line:
`sed "s/[a-fA-F0-9]\{8\}-[A-Fa-f0-9]\{4\}-[A-Fa-f0-9]\{4\}-[A-Fa-f0-9]\{4\}-[A-Fa-f0-9]\{12\}/$(uuidgen)/g"`

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
sed -i "s/$OLDUUID/$NEWUUID/g" file.txt
```

can't tell from your description, if you have multiple (different) UUIDs to replace of these, you may need to chain such operations.

Comment: Thanks Fredrik! This is why I hang out here!

Comment: sed -i "s/$OLDUUID/$NEWUUID/g" file.txt 
will replace all the UUID strings to all the same one, I need to replace all the UUID strings all different :)

Comment: There is one OLDUUID but multiple NEWUUIDs?

Comment: No, multiple OLDUUIDs and multiple NEWUUIDs generated by uuidgen.

Answer (score 0):

Way late to this, but if anyone else is looking to replace all UUIDs in a file with new ones, this awk command should help:

```sh
awk '/[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}-[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}-[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}-[A-Fa-f0-9]{12}/{"uuidgen" | getline uuid; close("uuidgen"); gsub(/[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}-[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}-[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}-[A-Fa-f0-9]{12}/, uuid)};{print}' myfile > mynewfile
```

For each line that contains a uuid, it will generate a new uuid and then substitute the existing uuid for the newly generated one.